# Does interactive measurement of a "particle" in a double-slit experiment affect what happened before that measurement

Tags: waves, time, double-slit-experiment

Yep, yet another question about the infamous "double-slit" experiment. I've read all the similar questions that pop up before submission of the question. I've read plenty :) over the years. I fell in love with quantum mechanics when I first read about this experiment in the 20th century and back to Young's in 1801. Copenhagen Interpretation, Many Worlds, Pilate Wave, and whatever else. Free Will or none. Determinism or Accident. Well, it wears thin. Let's just say it's all the above. But, if possible, I'd like to disregard "opinion" and ask a couple straightforward questions ("straightforward" immediately sounds like a paradox when it comes to the "science" of this unfortunately). But here goes:

The suppositions preceding these questions are: Light, elections, or buckyballs, i.e. any stream of energy projected at two slits and then terminating at a capture screen will create an interference pattern, even if each detection shows a quantized, discrete particle, overtime we get an interference pattern. If some sort of detection is introduced, which can measure where the particle is located, then it's possible to determine that the particle had passed through one slit or the other, and we no longer get the interference pattern over time at the capture screen.

1. Is there any experimental evidence that proves a single dot, on the capture screen, had passed through both slits somehow. (not measured or interfered with by human observation). In other words, do physicists "assume" light is going through both slits when not observed (even at dim power levels to induce something "quantum"). Or, is it a "fact" that it went through only one slit, but we just can't tell which slit, because we didn't measure it. Note: I get that a wave of light will go through both slits, but we are talking about an attempt to know "particle" nature via a double-slit apparatus, configured as such.
2. On the other hand, an effort to determine which slit the particle has passed, can be achieved by detecting the particle, which we then deduce as having passed through one slit or the other (even though it may be random - it does go through one slit and not both --- but only when observed).
3. So, if the above is happening, doesn't that mean that when a particle is measured, and we can say that it went through one or the other slit, and not both - then by doing that measurement - history has been changed! I say "history has been changed" to mean only that the trail of light between the projecting instrument, the slits, and the measuring instrument - is a history that would not have happened had the measurement never happened.

thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Effect comes after cause. The cause in this case is putting a detector near each slit to detect the particle. The effect is that the particle is absorbed or changes momentum, so that no interference pattern occurs. _the trail of light between the projecting instrument, the slits, and the measuring instrument - is a history that would not have happened had the measurement never happened_ But the particle still travels from the source to the slits to the point where it is detected. Why do you think this erases the particles _entire_ history?

Comment: @josephh thanks for the comment. I never claimed history is erased. There is a history when light is emitted "one quantum at a time": it makes dots on the screen and eventually builds up an interference pattern. But they don't know how because that's how a wave behaves, so they try to watch which slit it went though. When detected they find out which slit. So that implies it's history happens differently, and it's because it was measured. Also, what I've read about theory of relativity is that A may come before B, but also B may have come before A. Cause and effect are not objective things.

Comment: @quantumabsurd In relativity, if two events are potentially causally connected, i.e. one is inside the light cone of the other, then the cause always comes before the effect, even though two observers might disagree on the simultaneity of the events.

Comment: Wheeler has an interesting thought experiment which considers the history of two paths around a focusing gravitational body that might be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%27s_delayed-choice_experiment

Comment: @KDP thanks for the link! I had been aware of Wheeler and his delayed choice experiments, but now wish to dig into it more after reading through your link. We're in a simulation perhaps. idk.

Answer (score 0):

The DSE is indeed historically significant... as you say dating back to 1801 ... then the QM era hit in the early 1900s ... BUT the  DSE is NOT as significant as the nuclear age, the electronic age, WWI and WWII.  I would guesstimate that 1000 times more effort from physicists has gone into the latter vs the DSE ... as well as the best minds.  The DSE remains more in the world of academia compared to the revolutionary trends. And we all know academics are slow to adopt ... all the physics text books we use today  (high school , 1st year college) are still based on concepts from 1700s Huygen, 1801 Younge, etc no QM whatsoever ... and QM has suffered as the expense of the macro trends as well. So with that perspective here are answers to your questions:

1. For all particles (photon, electron, molecules) in a DSE experiment, the EM field is omnipresent, the EM field sees all the slits, the EM field sees the entire apparatus, the EM field continually reacts at the speed of light to changes.  The EM field as described today conducts energy as "photons" and forces with the "virtual photon" as a "place holder" particle. An excited atom/electron is already working with the field even before the photon is emitted. We do not have to say an electron splits into 2 pieces to create "interference" we merely need to conclude that the EM field has guided the particles to the preferred spots on the screen.
2. Whenever we observe a photon we destroy it ... whenever we observe a mass particle we are interacting with it, altering the EM field, if this occurs after the slits then the initial "wave function" (the one that saw the slits) is permanently altered and no interference.
3. By definition you can NOT change history .... but yes you are affecting the future.  Photons from a distant star on the way to earth can be bounced away back into space by a simple mirror.

When we have detectors for which slit for photons, the photons are destroyed, detectors for which slit could only be possible for electrons, molecules, neutrons.  There is the option to use polarizers as a form of "detection" but fundamentally you are just allowing photons of a certain polarization to see one slit or the other (or both if aligned) as far as the EM field is concerned.

Fundamentally the real photon is just following what the EM field tells it to do and it all started with an excited electron in the source.  The real photon's path can be changed mid-flight ... the EM field could say here's the best path for you ... and then something is rapidly changed in the apparatus and the EM field says go here instead ...its all dynamic and happening at the speed of light.

It's really all about the EM field which we can not observe directly ... the photon is what we observe but it plays no part in where it is told to go.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150750/discussion-on-answer-by-physicsdave-does-interactive-measurement-of-a-particle); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.